# Can we remove the highlight of the "reputation gain"?

Tags: bug, design, reputation-history

In my profile page, I can click on the number of gained reputation. This will create a highlight for this number and it's tooltip.

For me this highlight seems not to serve any purpose, and the highlight seems not even to be rendered correctly (stripes on the right of the tooltip).

Is there any hidden feature, that I missed? Or can we just remove this highlighting? Maybe even make clicking on the number navigating me to the recent reputation changes tab?

[image]

I'm using Google Chrome 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit) on macOS.

Comment: This looks like a browser issue. The highlight doesn't look the same for me.

Comment: @NathanOliver Try clicking on the green rep. It's just the CSS outline settings

Comment: @AlonEitan That does it.  I was just hovering.

Comment: @NathanOliver Now that is interesting! Exact same browser, different os, different behaviour...

Comment: [don't use outline:none](http://www.outlinenone.com/)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a real issue, I only see the outline after I click on the green reputation box. When I hover over the green reputation box no outline is shown.

Comment: For me, the highlight is centered on top of the green number, i.e. I can not click the number because the highlight is in the way. Using Firefox 52.2 on Debian 8

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue. Maybe someone can upvote one of my answers so I can help debugging.

Comment: @Zanon ...or give you a +500 bounty

Comment: @slartidan "Exact same browser, different os". Actually, Chrome is not the exact same browser on the different OS. For example, "the Chrome browser on iOS utilizes WebKit instead of Google’s Blink engine. It’s based on the same underlying foundation as Apple’s own Safari browser, but looks and feels like Chrome to the end user." [source](https://www.theverge.com/2017/5/10/15609706/google-chrome-windows-10-s-app-restrictions)